# improve this Linq with 2 Selects to same table

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

Hi i have this query that populates CompletedWords and CompletedRows with Childs that have Status Completed , the thing is it goes 2 times too the segments table instead of 1:

```
var query = _context.Submodules.Where(t => t.Id == id)
                    .Select(e => new Submodules{
                        Id = e.Id,
                        Name = e.Name,
                        Status = e.Status,
                        Token = e.Token,
                        ModuleId = e.ModuleId,
                        Gender = e.Gender,
                        TotalRows = e.TotalRows,
                        TotalWords = e.TotalWords,
                        CompletedWords = e.Segments.Where(a => a.Status == Abr.Recorded).Sum(y=> y.Wordcount),
                        CompletedRows = e.Segments.Where(a => a.Status == Abr.Recorded).Count()
                    }).ToList();
```

that translates to:

```
SELECT t.ID, t.name, t.status, t.token, t.moduleID,
t.gender, t.total_rows AS TotalRows, t.total_words AS TotalWords, 
(
    SELECT SUM(a.wordcount)
    FROM segments AS a
    WHERE (a.status = 1) AND (t.ID = a.submoduleID)
) AS CompletedWords, (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM segments AS a0
    WHERE (a0.status = 1) AND (t.ID = a0.submoduleID)
) AS CompletedRows
FROM submodules AS t
WHERE t.ID = @__id_0
```

as you can see to populate the CompletedWords and Rows ,
 it runs 2 selects where the Status==1 , just that one its Sum , the other is Count() , how can i merge them into .1 select .
Please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't worry too much about the SQL that EF generates unless you explicitly see a performance issue. Database engines are pretty adept at self-optimizing.

To answer your question though, this should work:

```
var query = _context.Submodules.Where(t => t.Id == id)
                    .Select(e => new {
                        Id = e.Id,
                        Name = e.Name,
                        Status = e.Status,
                        Token = e.Token,
                        ModuleId = e.ModuleId,
                        Gender = e.Gender,
                        TotalRows = e.TotalRows,
                        TotalWords = e.TotalWords,
                        ComletedSegments = e.Segments
                           .Where(a => a.Status == Abr.Recorded)
                           .Select(y => new { y.Wordcount })
                           .ToList()
                    }).ToList()
                    .Select(e => new Submodules{
                        Id = e.Id,
                        Name = e.Name,
                        Status = e.Status,
                        Token = e.Token,
                        ModuleId = e.ModuleId,
                        Gender = e.Gender,
                        TotalRows = e.TotalRows,
                        TotalWords = e.TotalWords,
                        CompletedWords = e.Sum(y=> y.Wordcount),
                        CompletedRows = e.Count()
                    }).ToList();
```

The first query selects an anonymous type to select the word count from applicable completed segments. The `ToList()` materializes this and executes the query. For the segments you could leave off the `.Select()` though this reduces the data selected to just the column we care about.

The second `.Select()` populates the view model by summing and counting the segments.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Yeah , mostly because its the first big software im developing for my new job , and have never done anything big from start to finish so i really want it to be good and learn from this . Already learnt how the select works today , this is even better . Really thanks!